# Add a prefix to all the element of an array of strings using javascript without iteration(.map() or loops)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Input: The Array of the strings

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
var prefix = 'prefix_';
```

Output: Each element in the array should be prefixed by 'prefix':

```
['prefix_a','prefix_b','prefix_c']
```

Comment: But, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I had tried and even added my own answer and accepted the more optimized and simple answer provided by void.

I did search on stackoverflow and other sites for the solutions but couldn't find any. Even the stackoverflows question suggester was showing similar questions in some other languages but not in javascript. @zakaria-acharki, thank you for pointing to the original question, I've upvoted the question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler, ES6 way using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```
const prefixArray = (array, prefix) => array.map(e => prefix+e);
```

***Demo:***

```js
let arr = ['a','b','c'];
const prefix = 'prefix_';

const prefixArray = (array, prefix) => array.map(e => prefix+e);

console.log(prefixArray(arr,prefix));
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use `Array.prototype.map` here, it transforms each element of the array based on the callback method.

```js
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
var prefix = 'prefix_';

var newArr = arr.map(el => prefix + el);
console.log(newArr);
```